# Why is my editor not giving me a syntax error, but compiling gives me a syntax error

Tags: python, syntax

I am using the editor PyCharm. It is not giving me an error on this code

```
import os
import sys

file = input("What file would you like to read from")

list = open(file, "r")


for line in list:
    command = ("python sqliv.py " + line.strip() + " -e google")
    os.system(command)
```

the editor is not giving me an error, but when i run it i get an error code on line 4 after input

```
./dorker: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

when I am running it, i am simply using the "./" in front of the file name.

What is the problem here? Does it think I am running a shell script if I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Linux the only way the console would know how to execute a text file is to have a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)). In your case, that would be have the first line be `#!/usr/bin/env python3`.

You could also run your program by giving it to the interpreter directly, and invoking `python3 dorker.py` instead.

Comment: Now i have a problem with the bash call in the for loop. It's saying the sqliv.py file does not exist, although i have moved the file it is calling into the same directory as the script that i have wrote.                                                                                                                python: can't open file 'sqliv.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: @slownickel Since you use a relative path, you must make sure the file can be accessed from current working directory i.e. the path you execute the main script from. If for example you invoke `python folder/dorker.py` then `sqliv.py` should be in `folder` parent instead. I'm not sure what PyCham uses as a current working directory. If you want to debug it, change temporarily your os.system command to "pwd" should output where the program expects the file in both cases.

Comment: I changed the command to the file path, but now it just sends it into a loop as it processes the file i am iterating over and its errors everytime.                                          ```   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/paradoxlsot/sqliv/sqliv.py", line 8, in <module>
    from src import std
  File "/home/paradoxlsot/sqliv/src/std.py", line 6, in <module>
    from terminaltables import SingleTable
ImportError: No module named terminaltables
``` is the error message